# wso2am-2.2.0 distributed setup - not publishing events

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using wso2am-2.2.0 with wum we are running gateway instances in a cluster as `-Dprofile=gateway-manager`

in the logs after the startup I see an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/micro/gateway/usage/publisher/util/UsagePublisherException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
.java:1032)
        ... 135 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.micro.gateway.usage.publisher.util.UsagePublisherException
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.l
```

When the gateway is used (an API is invoked), I see following exception:

```
TID: [-1234] []  ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.publisher.ThrottleDataPublisher} -  Error while publishing throttling events to global policy server {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.publisher.ThrottleDataPublisher}
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.publisher.ThrottleDataPublisher.publishNonThrottledEvent(ThrottleDataPublisher.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.doRoleBasedAccessThrottlingWithCEP(ThrottleHandler.java:349)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.doThrottle(ThrottleHandler.java:512)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.handleRequest(ThrottleHandler.java:460)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:158)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and as well seems the throttling data are not propagated (I don't see them processed by the analytics)

Comment: I believe I found the issue :( https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/2630

Comment: Yes, it's fixed in 2.5.0

Comment: @Bee thanks, in meanwhile we will just enable the data publisher, I believe there's nothing wrong with it :)

Comment: You can, but since gateway manager doesn't serve requests, it won't be publishing any data.